# How can I insert a C string into a dynamically allocated array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic

I am playing around with a series of functions that can be used to instantiate and add to a dynamically allocated array of strings in the C language.  The pointer to a pointer for the array is contained in a `struct` along with related metadata.  I have developed a function titled `init_string_vector` to instantiate the vector, another function titled `push_string_vector`that pushes strings to the end of the vector, `free_string_vector` to free all memory, and `insert_string_vector` which should allow a user to add data to any index in the vector, and not just the end of the vector such as would occur with the `push_string_vector` function.

The `insert_string_vector` function should check the string and ensure it has a null terminator (i.e. `"\0"`).  If it does not have a null terminator, the function should add the terminator.  Then, the function should check the allocated memory to ensure it is adequate, and if it is not, add the necessary memory with `realloc`.  Finally with the `memmove` function, it should move everything to the right of the user defined index by one index, and then insert the string to the now blank previously occupied index.  I can get everything in the function to work, but it appears that it is not allocating new memory, when it shifts everything one index to the right, and I can not figure out why.  My series of functions are listed below.  Any help would be appreicated.

```
typedef struct
{
    char **vector;
    size_t active_length;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t num_bytes;
} StringVector;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

StringVector init_string_vector(size_t length) {

    StringVector vec;

    char **ptr = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(char *));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("WARNING: Not enough available memory, exiting!\n");
        free(ptr);
    }
    vec.num_bytes = sizeof(char *);
    vec.active_length = 0;
    vec.allocated_length = length;
    vec.vector = ptr;
    return vec;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int push_string_vector(StringVector *vec, char *value, size_t length) {
    // Verify all values have null terminator
    char new_value[length];
    const char *test = ((char *)value) + length;
    int cmp = strcmp(test, "\0");
    if (cmp != 0) {
        memcpy(new_value, value, length + 1);
        memcpy(new_value + length, "\0", 1);
    }
    else memcpy(new_value, value, length);

    // Begin push
    value = strdup(new_value);
    if (!value) return 0;

    if (vec->active_length >= vec->allocated_length) {
        size_t size = 2 * (sizeof(char *) * (vec->allocated_length));
        char **resized = (char**)realloc(vec->vector, size);
        if (resized == NULL) {
            free(value);
            return 0;
        }
        resized[vec->active_length] = value;
        vec->vector = resized;
        vec->allocated_length *= 2;
    }
    else {
        vec->vector[vec->active_length] = value;
    }
    vec->active_length += 1;
    return 1;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void free_string_vector(StringVector *vec) {
    if (vec != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->allocated_length; i++) {
            free(vec->vector[i]);
        }
        free(vec->vector);
        vec->vector = NULL;
        vec->active_length = 0;
        vec->allocated_length = 0;
        vec->num_bytes = 0;
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int insert_string_vector(StringVector *vec, char *value, size_t length, size_t index) {
    // Verify all values have null terminator
    char new_value[length];
    const char *test = ((char *)value) + length;
    int cmp = strcmp(test, "\0");
    if (cmp != 0) {
        memcpy(new_value, value, length + 1);
        memcpy(new_value + length, "\0", 1);
        length += 1;
    }

    else memcpy(new_value, value, length);

    // Update vector size if necessary
    if (vec->active_length >= vec->allocated_length) {
        size_t size = 2 * (sizeof(char *) * (vec->allocated_length));
        char **resized = (char**)realloc(vec->vector, size);
        if (resized == NULL) {
            free(value);
            return 0;
        }
        vec->vector = resized;
        vec->allocated_length *= 2;
    }

    // Move appropriate portion of vector to the right and insert correct value
    memmove(vec->vector[index + 1], vec->vector[index], sizeof(char *));
    vec->vector[index] = value;
    vec->active_length += 1;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char a[6] = "Hello";
    StringVector vec = init_string_vector(7);
    push_string_vector(&vec, a, 6);
    char b[7] = "World!";
    push_string_vector(&vec, b, 7);
    char c[5] = "Goof"; 
    push_string_vector(&vec, c, 5);
    char d[8] = "Goodbye";
    insert_string_vector(&vec, d, 8, 1);
    // - It appears to successfully move everything after index 1
    //   to the right by one index and also add the string "Goodbye"
    //   to the vector, but then throws a segmentation error fault.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.active_length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", vec.vector[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `memmove(vec->vector[index + 1], vec->vector[index], sizeof(char *));` moves only one `char*` pointer. Shouldn't you multiply the `sizeof(char*)` by something like `(length-index)`?

Comment: @SupportUkraine that is a good catch with `memcpy` copying a `length + 1` to `length`. It does not solve the bigger problem, but it was a fix that was very much needed.